# Why does Coldfusion evaluate these numbers to not be equal?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

Why does coldfusion 8 evaluate 47.0000 * 15.40 eq 723.8 as false?

```
<cfset test = false />
<cfset a = 47.0000 />
<cfset b = 15.40 />
<cfset c = 723.8 />

<cfif (a * b) eq c>
  <cfset test = true />
</cfif>

<cfdump "#test#">
```

Test is output as false.

Comment: Floating point rounding errors - see http://corfield.org/entry/More_on_Floating_Point

Comment: because the real answer will be something like 723.99999999999912334123412545 or whatever.

Comment: Yeah, looks like 723.8000000000001.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [PrecisionEvaluate()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_m-r_13.html) to have CF use BigDecimals to do the math.

```
<cfset test = false />
<cfset a = 47.0000 />
<cfset b = 15.40 />
<cfset c = 723.8 />

<cfif PrecisionEvaluate(a * b) eq c>
  <cfset test = true />
</cfif>

<cfdump var="#test#" abort="true">
```

This results in the expected answer of true.

Comment: Interesting. a * b returns 723.8000000000001, but PrecisionEvaluate(a * b) returns 723.8000000000000

Comment: @JasonM - Because the former returns a `java.lang.Double`. The latter returns uses (and returns) a `java.math.BigDecimal` which is more precise.  Do a search on [ColdFusion floating point..](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[coldfusion]+floating+point+) there are tons of threads on this.

Comment: If you're still stuck with CFMX7 or older, you can instead use createObject("java", "java.math.BigDecimal") to make use of the Java class.